# Allow only digits with a single comma or period on ng-pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I'm tring to validate a number text box in angular. Only digits, a single comma, or a single dot is accepted. Alphabets and multiple dots or commans are invalid.

My regex is this:

```
/\d{1,}[,.]{0,1}\d{0,}/
```

There are some matching and non matching values here: https://regexr.com/3k4hl if needed.

Valid values:

```
1111
1.1111
111.111
111,11
1,1
1
```

Invalid values:

```
 1d11e
 1..1
 1.,1
 1,,1
 111.11.1
 1,111.11
```

But for whatever reason, angular textbox seems think everything is invalid, except an empty text box. I'm quite confused why:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="idNumber" ng-pattern="customPattern" />

// in .js
$scope.customPattern = '\d{1,}[,.]{0,1}\d{0,}';
```

Is there anything else I need to add?

Thanks.

<sup>ps: I'm on angular 1.5x</sup>

Comment: Use [`^\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/BX8SLX/1) (with `m` flag for online IDEs)

Comment: @ctwheels was about to post exactly the [same](https://regex101.com/r/Yq3fyp/1/) solution but you beat me to it :)

Comment: @ctwheels... that works! I spent like 20 minutes wondering if ng-pattern had some obscure spec -_- Can you please make that an answer so I can accept when SO allows me? thanks.

Comment: First of all, `'\d{1,}[,.]{0,1}\d{0,}'` is a string (not a `RegExp` literal), so `\d` should be `\\d`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/BX8SLX/1)

```
^\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?$
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `(?:[,.]\d+)?` Optionally match the following

  - `[,.]` Match a character in the set (either `,` or `.`)
  - `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

**Notes**:

- `{1,}` is the same as `+`
- `{0,1}` is the same as `?`
- `{0,}` is the same as `*`